# Unable to load .csv file in R on my new laptop

Tags: r, csv

I am facing a weird problem with R while loading a .csv file. Till last week I was working on a assignment in R having loaded a .csv file worth more than 1 million records. 
I got a new company laptop and installed R and the following packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(chron)
library(corrplot)
library(rio)
library(data.table)
library(openxlsx)
library(readr)
```

But surprisingly I am unable to run the `read.csv` command to read the csv file. I am using the following commands after giving the `setwd` command and getting the errors given below.

```
consumer_data <- read.csv("ConsumerElectronics.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input

consumer_data <- read.csv("ConsumerElectronics.csv", stringsAsFactors = "FALSE")

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

Don't know what's causing this problem. Earlier I was not getting this issue at all. Have I missed to install any package to read a csv file?
I want only the above code to work. Please do not provide any other alternative solution as this code was working earlier and reading the .csv file from the location where its stored.

Comment: can you provide a few lines of the csv file for reproducibility please?

Comment: `read.csv` does not depend on any of the packages you list. Do you still get an error after opening a new R session (without loading libraries, previous workspace / and rdata files)? Try removing the encoding .  Does the file definitely have data as you get this error when it is an empty file. Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please at the start of a new session.

Comment: Have you check and verified the working directory?  Since the readr package is loaded, I would suggest using read_csv instead.  It is generally faster and better at predicting the column classes.

Comment: My sense is to recommend you look at "What has changed?". a) Has the file been corrupted or changed? Is the file of zero length? Could you be calling a different 'read.csv' function from another package? In general, I recommend you fully qualify function calls `utils::read.csv` it will save much pain as your package list becomes larger. You will need to send a sample of the file for further debugging. My sense is someone may have changed the file format and not told anyone or the file may have been corrupted.